How to add form and fields in Shopify AppBridge Modal
I'm having issue on how to correctly add form and text fields to Shopify AppBridge Modal.
Shopify Discussion: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/how-to-add-form-and-fields-in-shopify-appbridge-modal/m-p/2799898#M474001
Here is how I create a modal:
let Button = window.AppBridge.actions.Button;
let okButton = Button.create(window.app, {label: I18n.pdf_report.form.button});

okButton.subscribe(Button.Action.CLICK, () => {
  // DO something and close the modal
  requestPdfReportModal.dispatch(Modal.Action.CLOSE)
});

let cancelButton = Button.create(window.app, {label: I18n.no_cancel});
cancelButton.subscribe(Button.Action.CLICK, () => {
  requestPdfReportModal.dispatch(Modal.Action.CLOSE);
});

const modalOptions = {
  title: "Title",
  message: "Message body",
  footer: {
    buttons: {
      primary: okButton,
      secondary: [cancelButton],
    },
  },
  size: "medium"
};

let Modal = window.AppBridge.actions.Modal;    
let requestPdfReportModal = Modal.create(window.app, modalOptions);
requestPdfReportModal.dispatch(Modal.Action.OPEN);

I find it hard to replace or put the form in Modal's content/body...
Applying this in Rails application with Stimulus JS.

Hi everyone - please share your thoughts on this issue. Thank you!
